# Latex: Push a Group of Words to the Right Edge in An Enumerate Environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate

I am preparing this document that entails I push some words to the right edge away from the others in an enumerated environment. I use `hfill` function to archive that, but when the line is long enough, it will overflow to the next page, thus, ending at the `left edge`.
The below is my MWE:

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \textbf{Indicate Option where applicable}: \hfill Not Applicable
        \item \textbf{Approval of Course-Work Examination Results by Board of Postgraduate Studies:} \hfill Not applicable  
        
        \item \textbf{Ratification of Course-Work Examination Results by Senate:} \hfill Not applicable
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Here is what my [image: trial output] looks like:

You can see that the first `item` looks good, while I want the second and the third item to look like the first by pushing the `Not applicable` words to the `right edge`.

**What I Want**

I want such overflowed words to be pushed to the `right edge` of the overflowed line.

Comment: I need help on this

Comment: Wrapping the "Not Applicable" into an `\mbox` will at least work for the second, but not the third one. Using `\nolinebreak\hfill\enspace\mbox{Not applicable}` will force it to be on the same line, but will cause a bad box.

Comment: The technique used by `amsthm` to set a `qed` box can be appled here:  `\leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill\quad\hbox{<text at right edge>}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have provided my solution attempt. You need to use `\hspace*` instead of `\hspace` so that TeX doesn't eat all the glue at the beginning of the next line. This makes the `Not~Applicable` text display correctly in the 3rd item.

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{microtype}%added to fix bad boxes
%
\usepackage{enumitem}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{enumerate}
%
\item
\textbf{Indicate Option where applicable}:
\hspace*{\fill}Not~Applicable
%
\item
\textbf{Approval of Course-Work Examination Results by Board of Postgraduate Studies:}
\hspace*{\fill}Not~Applicable  
%
\item
\textbf{Ratification of Course-Work Examination Results by Senate:}
\hspace*{\fill}Not~Applicable
%
\end{enumerate}
%
\end{document}
```